# How to change color scheme in corrplot

Tags: r, colors, r-corrplot

I am using `corrplot` in R to visualise a correlation-coefficient matrix as follows.

```
library(corrplot) 
library(datasets)
corrplot(abs(cor(mtcars)), method="color", tl.pos="n", cl.lim = c(0,1))
```

[image]

The default colour scheme is ***blue***-based. However, I would like to change it to ***red***-based. I know I need to use `colorRampPalette` to specify colours I want. However, I could not figure out what colour codes to use. Could anyone help me with this, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried a [Color Picker](http://www.colorpicker.com/)?

Comment: When asking for plotting help, it's best to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Also, since `corrplot` does not appear to be a function in base R, clearly indicate which packages you are using,

Comment: I think that at the middle (section:  Using Different Color Spectrum) of this page there is what you are looking for: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html

Comment: @MrFlick I made some changes. I think you can reproduce this yourself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use red, you can define your own colorRampPalette as you've alread mentioned. Just note that the plot seems to set the range of colors from -1 to 1 (even if you adjust the `cl.lim` value). Thus you still need to define colors for the -1 to 0 range in your ramp. For example

```
corrplot(abs(cor(mtcars)), method="color", tl.pos="n", 
    cl.lim=c(0,1), col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"))(200))
```

will produce

[image]

and even though we defined "blue" in the color palette, it doesn't show up because we limited the color bar to values greater than 1.

This "unused" part of the color gradient cab be seen with the original version as well if you take out `cl.lim`

```
corrplot(abs(cor(mtcars)), method="color", tl.pos="n")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The function colorRampPalette returns a function that takes a numeric argument:

```
corrplot(abs(cor(mtcars)), method="color",
         col= colorRampPalette(c("white","pink", "red"))(10) ,
         tl.pos="n", cl.lim = c(0,1))
```

[image]

The default is defined with this color spectrum:

```
col2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#67001F", "#B2182B", "#D6604D", "#F4A582", "#FDDBC7",
        "#FFFFFF", "#D1E5F0", "#92C5DE", "#4393C3", "#2166AC", "#053061"))
```

This would give you a wider range of reds:

```
colnew <- colorRampPalette(c("#670000", "#B20000", "#D60000", "#F40000", "#FD0000", "#FFFFFF"))
```

And I thought adding a "brown" at the end extended the range for better visual separation:

```
col= colorRampPalette(c("white","lightpink", "red","brown"))(10)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess another way is to simply reverse the order of colour codes in default col2.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to remove the white grid line, please? I tried 'addgrid.col=NULL'. It did not work.

Comment: `addgrid.col="transparent"`