# Customized correlation plot color

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-correlation, r-corrplot, ggcorrplot

Is there any way to customize the correlation plot in R for example in the below plot [image]

I want to have different color value for example if value lie between 0.5 to 0.7 then make it green and below that keep it to blue and above 0.7 keep it to red

I used below code for correlation plot

```
library(corrplot)
data_matrix<-as.matrix(data)
corr_mat=cor(data_matrix,method="pearson")
corrplot(corr_mat,method = "number")
```

Comment: do you need plain colours or with a gradient? do you mean 0.5 and 0.7 in absolute value? or you want all negatives to be blue? do you need the numbers to be displayed or just the squares/circles?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Have you looked at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743983/how-to-change-color-scheme-in-corrplot)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better a `ggplot`. It's easier to customize.

Adjust the size of the text with the additional argument `size` inside `geom_text` if you need to.

```
# given a correlation matrix
corr_matrix <- cor(mtcars)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

corr_matrix %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "var1") %>% 
  gather(var2, value, -var1) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = var1, y = var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, digits = 2))) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "Corr", title = "Correlation Matrix") +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
        limits = c(-1,1),

        # here choose the colours you want
        colours = c("blue", "green", "red"), 

        # here choose the intervals you want (must be inside rescale!)
        values = scales::rescale(c(-1, 0.5, 0.7, 1)))
```

[image]

Just with numbers [personally I'd go with the first one]

```
corr_matrix %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "var1") %>% 
  gather(var2, value, -var1) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = var1, y = var2, colour = value)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "gray20", fill = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, digits = 2))) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "Corr", title = "Correlation Matrix") +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "green", "red"),
                       values = scales::rescale(c(-1, 0.5, 0.7, 1)),
                       limits = c(-1,1))
```

[image]

---

EDIT

I added this to solve the issue related to labels sorting.

First of all, I'll edit `mtcars` to make it look like your data.

```
colnames(mtcars) <- paste0("Month", 1:11)
mtcars$Month12 <- rnorm(32)
```

Okay, now let's proceed with the graph. We just need to add a small edit: we make the var names as ordered factors.

```
corr_matrix <- cor(mtcars)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

corr_matrix %>% 
    as_tibble(rownames = "var1") %>% 
    gather(var2, value, -var1) %>% 
    
    # here is the additional line you need!
    mutate(across(c(var1, var2), factor, levels = paste0("Month", 1:12), ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
    
    ggplot(aes(x = var1, y = var2, fill = value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(value, digits = 2))) +
    labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "Corr", title = "Correlation Matrix") +
    coord_fixed() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_gradientn(
        limits = c(-1,1),
        
        # here choose the colours you want
        colours = c("blue", "green", "red"), 
        
        # here choose the intervals you want (must be inside rescale!)
        values = scales::rescale(c(-1, 0.5, 0.7, 1)))
```

[image]

It works with `dplyr` version >= 1.0.0.

If you don't have it, use this instead:

```
  mutate_at(c("var1", "var2"), factor, levels = paste0("Month", 1:12), ordered = TRUE) %>%
```

Comment: Thanks Edo, I really appreciate for the solution
I am able to generate the plot but labels are not in sync for example it should be Month1,Month2.... Month12 in this order.

Image Link for the plot generated

https://i.imgur.com/9YBtyui.png

Comment: @ Edo,
Tried using reorder but  the label is not getting arranged can you help me on this.
Below is what I am tried but it is not coming out proper 


ggplot(aes(x = reorder(var1,desc(-var1)), 
             y = reorder(var2,desc(var2)), fill = value))

Comment: link after adding reorder 
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(var1,-desc(var1)), 
             y = reorder(var2,desc(var2)), 
             fill = value))
https://imgur.com/Zw6RXdu

Comment: okay, look at my edit. You need to make it into a factor and sort the levels manually. That's the way to go.

Comment: getting error
Error in across(c(var1, var2), factor, levels = paste0("Month", 1:12),  : 
  could not find function "across"

Comment: I wrote it already in my answer: if it doesn't work it's because your dplyr version is too old. Just use the other solution I wrote on the bottom.