# How is the colouring working, when I plot a correlogram with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-corrplot

So, I found this code [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/97-correlation-ellipses.html):

```
# Libraries
library(ellipse)
library(RColorBrewer)
 
# Use of the mtcars data proposed by R
data <- cor(mtcars)
 
# Build a Pannel of 100 colors with Rcolor Brewer
my_colors <- brewer.pal(5, "Spectral")
my_colors <- colorRampPalette(my_colors)(100)
 
# Order the correlation matrix
ord <- order(data[1, ])
data_ord <- data[ord, ord]
plotcorr(data_ord , col=my_colors[data_ord*50+50], mar=c(1,1,1,1))
```

which basically allow me to plot a correlogram. Everything is fine and clear, I can happily apply the code to my dataset and no problem.

I wonder, though, what is happening with the colours of the plot. In particular I don't understand this specific piece of code `col=my_colors[data_ord*50+50]`. I played a bit with it:

```
n <- 1; plotcorr(sortedCMat, col=cPal[sortedCMat*n+n]);
n <- 8; plotcorr(sortedCMat, col=cPal[sortedCMat*n+n]);
n <- 14; plotcorr(sortedCMat, col=cPal[sortedCMat*n+n]);
n <- 18; plotcorr(sortedCMat, col=cPal[sortedCMat*n+n]);
n <- 100; plotcorr(sortedCMat, col=cPal[sortedCMat*n+n]);
n <- 40; plotcorr(sortedCMat, col=cPal[sortedCMat*n+n]);
n <- 50; plotcorr(sortedCMat, col=cPal[sortedCMat*n+n]);
```

Apparently, only values of `n` around the 50 threshold seem to provide a good looking plot.

I also looked at the help page and this is what I get:

```
 # Colour the ellipses to emphasize the differences.  The color range
 # is based on RColorBrewer's Reds and Blues (suggested by Gregor Gorjanc)
 
 corr.mtcars <- cor(mtcars)
 ord <- order(corr.mtcars[1,])
 xc <- corr.mtcars[ord, ord]
 colors <- c("#A50F15","#DE2D26","#FB6A4A","#FCAE91","#FEE5D9","white",
             "#EFF3FF","#BDD7E7","#6BAED6","#3182BD","#08519C")   
 plotcorr(xc, col=colors[5*xc + 6])
```

and yet, they are doing the same thing here. So my question is...what is going on here? Apparently [the function works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743983/how-to-change-color-scheme-in-corrplot) even without this *trick* so I am wondering what is its purpose, aside from the fact that I need it to make my plot looking good.

Comment: 50 is the index of the middle color. When you have a correlation of, say, -0.25 (-.0.25*50 + 50 = 37.5), the color in position 38 in the color vector will be shown. If the correlation were higher (0.8*50+50 = 90), you'll get a color further up in the vector. As 50 is the middle point and there are 100 colors, this formula will work for any values of "data_ord" between -1 and 1, which all correlations are

Comment: yes, you're right! I didn't think about the fact that I am using 100 colours in the palette range and 50 is right half of it. Of course! If you wish, since I guess this is the answer, you can transform your comment into an actual answer and that will be it.